# Add values using FOREACH loop

Tags: php

I have a group of arrays, the first one indexed by [TEAM] and the next ones indexed by [USER]. I need to complete the first array accumulating values of the [ITEMS] key of the other arrays

```
// $TEAMS

[TEAM1] => Array
(
[TEAM] => TEAM1
[ITEMS] => 
)

// $USERS

[USER1] => Array
(
[USER] => USER1
[TEAM] => TEAM1
[ITEMS] => 12
)

[USER2] => Array
(
[USER] => USER2
[TEAM] => TEAM1
[ITEMS] => 18
)
```

That's my code:

```
foreach ($TEAMS $key => $value) {
$TEAMS[$key]['ITEMS'] = $USERS[$TEAMS[$key]['TEAM']]['ITEMS'];
}
```

I need obtain this:

```
[TEAM1] => Array
(
[TEAM] => TEAM1
[ITEMS] => 30
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not getting your array values exactly but it may help you

```
foreach ($TEAMS as $key => $value) {

        foreach ($USERS as $keyu => $valueu) {
            if($TEAMS[$key]['TEAM']==$valueu['TEAM']){
                $TEAMS[$key]['ITEMS'] = $TEAMS[$key]['ITEMS'] + $valueu['ITEMS'];
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: @JuandelaCuadra It's my pleasure. Please do upvote and mark as correct my answer :)